# Directory missing after rebooting Debian server

Tags: linux, debian, backup

I rebooted a Debian 6.0.4 server and `/opt/storage/` went missing. `/opt/cronjobs/`directory is present.

There is a backup from 4 months ago. I restored it and in that the `/opt/storage/` is present, but it doesn't have any files inside. So for me it seems that the directory/files went missing after reboot.

Which logs I should check to investigate what happened with the system?

I know Debian 6 is old, having proper backups is must and untested backups are not backups. I just started in the company and I'm the only guy responsible for this server.

Comment: Maybe `/opt/storage` is a mountpoint? Check `/proc/partitions` versus the output of `df` to see if you might be missing a mount

Comment: `df` lists `/dev/sda1`, `tmpfs`, `udev` and another `tmpfs`. `/dev/sda1` is the only data partition. I tried to check mounting errors from `/var/log/dmesg`, but found none.

Comment: Maybe an NFS (or SAN or whatever) mount? `/opt/storage` quite sounds like that ...

Comment: I've been suspecting that, but documentation for this server is zero, so I don't know where the NFS or SAN server could be. What would be a way to check where the other end of network share could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the `/opt/storage` is a NFS share from file `/etc/fstab`. I've been trying to figure out this by reading logs and Googling "directory missing...".

This might be useful command for figuring out which log files have information about mounts:

`grep -e mount -lR /var/log 2> /dev/null`

And this command shows if there are NFS share mounted at the moment:

`mount -l | grep nfs`

Hope this will help somebody else. Thanks for the help @EugenRieck

**EDIT:**

Now that I think, this probably happened because I rebooted a Windows 2008 R2 primary DC at the same time. The share was mounted with DNS name. Secondary DC was also frozen at the time. No DNS server working - no NFS share to mount.

What I find peculiar is that the Debian couldn't mount the NFS with a new reboot, when the AD DC was up and running.